# Как в VIM использовать Tab как Esc, а Ctrl+i использовать как Tab?

Tags: vim

Как сделать так, чтобы в `VIM` в режиме ввода можно было выходить в нормальный по нажатию на `Tab`, но использовать `Ctrl+i` как `Tab`

Comment: @wwju  а какое-нибудь другое сочетание клавиш, не CTRL-I можно? Дело в том, что код CTRL-I -- это и есть код табуляции. Если Вы работаете со скан-кодами клавиатуры -- дело другое, но в эмуляции терминала их различить трудно.

Comment: @alexlz, я не в терминале - я в GVIM. Но вот сделать, чтобы оно работало, мне удалось - видимо, я до того, как ввести ваши команды, я вводил другие. И, как я написал ниже, заработало. Но, к сожалению, после перезагрузки, они не работают. Ну да ладно, пока что придется оставить эту затею на потом. Или вообще сделать свою собственную клавиатуру :)

Comment: Кстати, вот хорошая русская документация по поводу ремапинга символов http://catscpp.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/settings/.vim/doc/map.rux

Comment: @wwju Колоться -- так колоться. Назовите ещё ОС. (у меня под убунтой gvim ведёт себя так же, как и vim).

Comment: @alexlz, ОС - Linux Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: И что у Вас говорит :imap после первой :inoremap и после второй?

Comment: inoremap <Tab> <Esc>
imap <tab>
  i <tab> * <esc>

inoremap <C-I> <Tab>
imap <c-i>
  i <tab> * <tab>

Comment: @wwju Всё, завязываю с этим вопросом. Vim большой и непростой, и х. с ним. Так у меня gvim себя ведёт в режиме compatible (обычный -- nocompatible). Правда вывод :imap для моих определений идёт чёрным цветом (в режиме nocp -- голубым). По табуляции режим ввода не прекращается. Отрывок из хелпа key-codes

notation meaning      equivalent decimal value(s) ~
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
<Nul>  zero   CTRL-@   0 (stored as 10) *<Nul>*
<BS>  backspace  CTRL-H   8 *backspace*
<Tab>  tab   CTRL-I   9 *tab* *Tab*

Успехов!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Привет, в *~/.vimrc* записать привязку вида

```
inoremap <Tab> <Esc>
inoremap <C-I> <Tab>
```

;-)

Comment: И всё заработает? Ух ты! А почему у меня не хочет?

Comment: @parkov http://pastebin.com/gxX49w9f

Comment: Спасибо :) Кстати, для @alexz - для того, чтобы проверить, на что назначены эти клавиши, можете набрать :imap <кнопка>, и VIM покажет, что делает эта кнопка

Comment: @wwju чудесно! Вводим первую команду, получаем результат

    :inoremap <Tab> <Esc>
    :imap
    i  <Tab>       * <Esc>

Вводим вторую, и получаем вполне закономерный, ожидаемый результат

    :inoremap <C-I> <Tab>
    :imap
    i  <Tab>       * <Tab>

Всё правильно и понятно. Не понятно, как это должно удовлетворять условиям задачи

Comment: @alexz вы правы, я невнимательно отнесся к вопросу.